# How to change URL of OntClass instance in Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I need to add URL for all the Anonymous class in one Ontology. But I cannot find a method to do it.
The code almost like this:

```
OntModel ontoModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
ontoModel.read(xxxxx, null);

ExtendedIterator<OntClass> iter = ontoModel.listClasses();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if(ontClass.isAnon()) {
            //Add URL to the anonymous ontClass
            String newURL = getNewURL();
            //ontClass.addProperty( ontoModel.createProperty( "rdf","about" ) , newURL);// I tried this, but it is useless
        }
}
```

I need to give a URL for the ontClass . So It could change to a URLResource and I could get the URL by ontClass.getURL().

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper function to do this : `ResourceUtils.renameResource`.  It will rename all uses (subject and object positions in triples).